# How to compare two numbers

Tags: shell-script, solaris, numeric-data

I have following two values:

```
val1=13.2.8
val2=15.0.5
```

I want to check if `val1` is less than `val2` or not, I tried this:

```
echo "if ($val1<$val2) 1" | bc
```

But it is throwing following error:

```
syntax error on line 1, teletype
```

For normal floating numbers it is working fine.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Excluding GNU tools, I assume based on the Solaris tag?

Answer (score 4):

Those aren't numbers, at least not in the mathematical sense. What you probably want is *version string* comparison, provided by GNU (and possibly other) `sort --version-sort`/`sort -V`:

```
if [[ "$(sort --version-sort <<< "$(printf '%s\n' "$val1" "$val2")" | head --lines=1)" = "$val1" ]]
then
    echo "$val1 <= $val2"
fi
```

Comment: I am getting this error : `head: illegal option -- lines=1
sort: illegal option -- version-sort
usage: sort [-cCmu] [-o output] [-T directory] [-S mem]
        [-dfiMnr] [-b] [-t char] [-k keydef] [+pos1 [-pos2]] files...`

Comment: Looks like your version of `head` and `sort` have different options. Look at the man pages to find which map to the options I've used.

Comment: If you have Solaris 11, try `gsort`. a lot of GNU tools are available nowadays but these are not de default tools.

Answer (score -2):

You can not use arithmetic comparison for these values. You should use string comparison.
In bash you can use '[[' :

```
[[ $val2 > $val1 ]] && echo "$val2 is greater than $val1"
```

Comment: Why demoting? Those are not real numbers.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing it's because lexical comparison will likely give the "wrong" answer for cases like `val1=3.2.8`, `val2=15.0.5`